# Is it possible to run iCloud Drive on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, icloud

I'm active Apple user, I have MacBook at home, but Linux PC on the work. One of most annoying thing for me is sync my personal data between home, work and mobile devices (like documents etc). At the moment my main cloud storage is iCloud (it is integrate to OS X). Today I tried to install iCloud for Windows via Wine, but it didn't work.

Is there any possible ways to configure Wine or other software? I know about icloud.com, I need automatic sync as Dropbox.

Comment: This question is pretty old - maybe some new ways to do that have appeared?

Comment: @ringø I didn't found solution and I had started to take my MacBoot to my work. But it is still interesting to solve this problem for community.

Comment: Yes @gephaest it would be great if there is solution for this.
I also have Macs at home but have Linux as desktop at work.
Dropbox work great on Linux...

Answer (score 12):

Aside from the iCloud services with more standard protocols (Mail, Contacts, Calendar) it doesn't look like there's a way to provide "in sync" access to iCloud Drive, aside from visiting [iCloud Drive](https://www.icloud.com/#iclouddrive) in a browser…

- [Q: How do I use icloud with Linux?](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3689451) (Apple Discussions)

---

Also, not that this helps much for Linux (Ubuntu), but Apple *does* provide a Windows (7+) client:

- [iCloud for Windows](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT204283)

Comment: what about using the windows icloud software on linux with wine? though the page on winehq is not encouraging https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=14545

Answer (score 0):

There *do* seem to be Linux apps/packages that support iCloud Drive for some distributions. Here's one I found just now:

- [Install iCloud on Ubuntu using the Snap Store | Snapcraft](https://snapcraft.io/install/icloud-for-linux/ubuntu)

Comment: That app just wraps icloud.com in a WebView, unfortunately. It is exactly as good as opening icloud.com in a browser.